# How much ground truth error does the KITTI dataset have?

Tags: c++, camera-calibration, lidar, pose-estimation, kitti

I visualized KITTI odometry dataset with ground truth and Velodyne point cloud data.
http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php

The height of the camera position seems different after the loop in the sequence. I am not sure this is normal or I misunderstood something. When you use this data as ground truth, you modify something or you use it as it is?

This is the code which loads the poses txt file

```cpp
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open(poses_path, std::ios::in);
assert(infile.good());

std::string l1;
while (getline(infile, l1)) {
    double p00, p01, p02, p03;
    double p10, p11, p12, p13;
    double p20, p21, p22, p23;
    if (std::sscanf(l1.c_str(), 
        "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",
        &p00,&p01,&p02,&p03,
        &p10,&p11,&p12,&p13,
        &p20,&p21,&p22,&p23) == 12) {
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read camera intrinsics!\n";
        infile.close();
        return;
    }

    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> R;
    R << p00, p01, p02, p10, p11, p12, p20, p21, p22;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> t;
    t << p03, p13, p23;

    Sophus::SE3d cam2World(R, t);
    vCam2World.push_back(cam2World);
}

infile.close();
```

This is an image of a 3D point cloud viewed horizontally from close to it.
As you can see, the camera position after the loop is at a different height.
I converted Velodyne data to the depth value on the camera coordinate and also visualized.
Then, the point cloud of the car is also a bit shifted.

[image]

This is a bird's-eye view and it seems good.

[image]

This is a color image overlaid with depth values from Velodyne. It seems good too.

[image]

Comment: Not a C++ question?

Comment: My question is about the dataset, but I wrote the code with C++. So I added a tag of C++. Is this not good?

Comment: Is the question about the code, or the dataset?

Comment: about the dataset

Comment: so the code is not relevant?

Comment: My question is about the dataset. But, I may be using the data set incorrectly. In this case, my question is about code.

Comment: Well, the code doesn't use the data set, anyway, it just reads camera transformations from a file.

Answer (score 0):

the main difference is ground truth poses in left rgb camera frame. You might need to calibrate poses into that frame.